# Capturing camera input on android

Tags: android, camera, onactivityresult

I'm trying to capture a picture from camera and simply print a log.

Here's my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2; //Used to identify the activity
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1; //Used to request permission to the user

private Context context = CameraActivity.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

    //Check for permissions
    if(Permissions.checkPermissionsArray(context, Permissions.PERMISSIONS_CAMERA)){
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        Log.d("dd", "ee");
                    }
                }
        );

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }
    else {
        Permissions.requestPermissions(this, Permissions.PERMISSIONS_CAMERA, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    setupBottomNavigationView();
}
```

Now, the camera acquisition works just fine. I'm able to successfully take a picure, but no log message is shown. So I guess I'm doing the activityResult piece wrong.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. I was using the method `startActivity` instead of the `activityResultLauncher.launch` one.

Answer (score 0):

Add on activity result after on activity.

```
    public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
        private static final int ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2; //Used to identify the activity
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1; //Used to request permission to the user
        
        private Context context = CameraActivity.this;
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
        
            //Check for permissions
            if(Permissions.checkPermissionsArray(context, Permissions.PERMISSIONS_CAMERA)){
                ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                                Log.d("dd", "ee");
                            }
                        }
                );
        
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent , ACTIVITY_NUMBER );
                
            }
            else {
                Permissions.requestPermissions(this, Permissions.PERMISSIONS_CAMERA, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        
          

  setupBottomNavigationView();
    }
```

and then add on Activity result.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            Log.d("dd", selectedImage.toString );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` is deprecated long ago...